# Access Pivot Query returns dates not included in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, pivot

Straight forward pivot query below running in access 2010. I'm hoping to extract login/logout records between dates in August - However September records are included in the result - I cannot fathom why.

```
TRANSFORM Min([TimeIn]+" - "+[iSparky]![TimeOut]) AS InOut
SELECT iSparky.NAME, Count(iSparky.TimeIn) AS [Total Of TimeIn]
FROM iSparky
WHERE ((([iSparky]![DateIn])>#8/15/2013# And ([iSparky]![DateIn])<#8/20/2013#))
GROUP BY iSparky.NAME
ORDER BY [iSparky]![DateIn]
PIVOT [iSparky]![DateIn];
```

Any Suggestions would be most appreciated - thanx for your time and efforts as always :)

Comment: What is the type of [iSparky]![DateIn] ?

Comment: ooo u hit it right on the head - thanks for putting light in the right spot was text changed to date/time. Such a blonde some days! ty ty  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. error with () in WHERE

   (([iSparky]![DateIn]>#8/15/2013#) And ([iSparky]![DateIn]<#8/20/2013#))
2. Type mismatch of [iSparky]![DateIn]

Comment: I'm afraid even with the amendment to the code the results are still the same. Perhaps view http://www.isparky.co.za/images/dates.png for unexpected result? Thanx for your time :)